# How to add explicit header to each operation in Axis2?

Tags: soap, header, apache-axis, axis, soapheader

In Axis2 webservice, genearted wsdl should contain custom soap:header tag bind with each operation. Is there any way to do this?
For eg:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetSearchMessage">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://services.ex.com" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input name="GetSearchContractRequestType">
    <soap:header message="tns:GetRequestHeader_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal" />
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="GetSearchContractResponseType">
    <soap:header message="tns:GetRequestHeader_Headers" part="RequestHeader" use="literal" />
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```